# Epoch's steps taking too long on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to train a model which in my opinion is taking too long compared to other datasets given that it's taking about 1h and 20min to complete one epoch. I think that the problem is because the dataset is not being stored on ram, but I'm not sure of this.

The code is the following:

```
def load_data():

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(path1, target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=32, class_mode="binary")

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(path2, target_size=(200, 200),batch_size=32, class_mode="binary")

    return train_generator, test_generator
```

Model:

- Sequential model
- 2 Convolutional layers with 32 neurons, activation = relu.
- 1 Convolutional layer with 64 neurons, activation = relu.
- Flattening and Dense layer, activation = relu.
- Dropout of 0.5
- Output layer (Dense) with sigmoid activation.
- Adam optimizer.
- Loss: binary cross entropy.

Fit:

```
model.fit_generator(x, steps_per_epoch=500, epochs=50, validation_data=y, validation_steps=len(y)/32, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

- My dataset has 1201 images and 2 classes.
- I built the model following [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) tutorial.
- My GPU is a GTX 1060 3gb.
- 8gb of ram.
- The images are being reshaped to 200x200.

If you could help me I'd appreciate it. Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**
I've done what Matias Valdenegro suggested, even though it's true that the time it takes to complete an epoch is lower, what I realized is that it takes my GPU 10s to complete a step. This is what I really wanted to improve. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you believe problem originates from GPU, you can use `nvprof <your_program> [args...]`  to get CUDA kernel execution time.

Comment: Why did you set steps per epoch to 500?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I tried with 32 but the results are terrible and in the tutorial they are set to 2000 with 50 epochs. So I thought that 500 would be a good idea given that I got nice results in a "decent" amount of time (4hs).

Comment: @Kh40tiK I think that the problem is the ImageDataGenerator or the fit_generator but as I said I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your `steps_per_epoch` are completely wrong, you should set this parameter to number of training images divided by the batch size.

What this parameter does is it tells keras how many batches to pull from the generator in order to *declare* an epoch. If you set it too high (as you did), then keras is pulling multiple epochs of data before showing you one epoch, which explains the performance issue that you see.

You cannot set this parameter arbitrarily.

Comment: I'll try again with 32, but why do they use 2000 in the tutorial?

Comment: @SantiagoPardal I can't guess why they set it to 2000, ask the people that wrote that tutorial. It could just be that their dataset was larger.

Comment: @MatiasValdengro I edited the question, please take a look at it. Is the time normal? Thanks!